# chef-vault requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0 | Error using with Terraform

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, terraform

Am using Terraform to spin up instances in Openstack and use the chef provisioner for bootstrap my node to chef in terraform code. I do have a Chef vault where i put my secrets. 
But

> terraform apply

is giving the below error

> openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.node.0 (chef):  chef-vault requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0.

Please find the code snippet below:

```
provisioner "chef" {

      node_name = "test${format("0%03d", count.index+1)}"
      environment = "${var.environment}"
      run_list = ["role[dev_default]"]
      version = "${var.chef-client_version}"
      recreate_client = true
      server_url = "${var.chef001_server}/organizations/${var.chef_org}"
      user_name = "${var.chef_username}"
      user_key = "${var.chef_user_key}"
      vault_json = "${file("scripts/vault.json")}
}
```

It would be great to some insights on the same?

Regards,
Sunil

Comment: Does your image already have Chef installed?

Comment: Yes, Chef gets installed while bootstrapping

Comment: Update: I changed the Chef version to 12.14.89 , which seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered via comments, user was using a very old version of Chef which is incompatible with current vault.